# Use grep to delete any string containing year less than 2014

Tags: r, regex

Edited to add more context and data 5/12/2017

Using R version 3 on Windows

I have a data frame data2:

```
'data.frame':   1504 obs. of  14 variables:
$ Member.Name       : chr  "A" "B" "C"... 
$ MSTATUS           : Factor w/ 14 levels "","ACTIVE","ACTIVE;CHANGEDROLES;NONQUALIF",..: 13 2 2 2 2 4 13 13 2 13 ...
$ MCAT              : Factor w/ 9 levels "","EDNEWCLASS",..: 5 4 9 6 6 6 9 9 4 4 ...
$ SALUTATION        : Factor w/ 822 levels "","Aaron","Abigail",..: 285 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 5 5 ...
$ MEM_SUBCATEGORY   : Factor w/ 22 levels "","AGENCYCEO",..: 22 6 8 15 8 6 8 1 6 6 ...
$ MEM_SUBTYPE       : Factor w/ 25 levels "","AGENCY","AGENCYCEO",..: 24 6 6 20 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
$ COUNTRY           : Factor w/ 33 levels "","AE","AT","AU",..: 33 33 33 33 7 33 33 33 33 33 ...
$ F500              : Factor w/ 243 levels "","#1406 on Forbes Global 2000 ($11B)",..: 1 1 96 1 242 1 147 1 1 76 ...
$ OPT_LINE          : Factor w/ 1467 levels "","(Formerly) CondÃ© Nast",..: 1 1170 609 1333 251 1427 444 258 814 1207 ...
$ FLAGS             : chr  "2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO" "" "PUFOUNDINGMEMBER" "2014FLESPEAKER" ...
$ FLAGS_DESCR       : chr  "2014 Page Jam Participant, \nPhoto on File" "" "Page Up Founding Member" "2014 Future Leaders Experience Speaker" ...
$ Enroll.Date       : Date, format: "2012-12-04" "2010-08-24" "2013-09-20" "2013-05-06" ...
$ Expiration.Date   : Date, format: "2014-12-31" "2017-12-31" "2017-12-31" "2017-12-31" ...
$ Sponsorship.Amount: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

For the FLAGS variable, I'd like to remove all row elements that contain a year less than 2014.

```
head(data2$FLAGS, n=3)
[1] "2011PRESIDENTS, \n2012CHAIRMANSCOUNCIL, \n2016CHAIRCOUNCIL" ""                                                          
[3] "2012COI"
```

So that FLAGS will look like:

```
head(data2$FLAGS, n=3)
[1] "\n2016CHAIRCOUNCIL" ""                                                          
[3] ""
```

The rows with no values can either be blank or NA, BUT if a row does contain an event with a year >=2014 and an event with a year <2014 than just delete the event less than 2014 and keep the other events in the row.

Comment: Is the year always at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, year is always at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

This regex works for your example. The idea is to match the first 3 characters of year for those elements that fail and drop them.

```
FLAGS[-grep("20(0|1[0123])", FLAGS)]
[1] "2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO" "\n2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT"  "\n2014PUSPONSOR, \nPHOTO"
```

or, using invert, you'd have

```
FLAGS[grep("20(0|1[0123])", FLAGS, invert=TRUE)]
```

Note that it won't catch pre-2000s and you should be cautious if there are other "numeric" values in the vector.

---

To return a vector of the same length, with NAs replacing the earlier years, you could use `is.na<-` and `grepl` like this

```
is.na(FLAGS) <- grepl("20(0|1[0123])", FLAGS)
```

**original data**

```
FLAGS<-c("2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO", "2001ANNUALCONFERENCECOMM", 
         "\n2011GOVERNANCE", "\n2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT", "2013NEWMEMBERNOMINATOR", 
         "\n2014PUSPONSOR, \nPHOTO")
```

---

given OP's second question. The following more or less works:

```
sapply(strsplit(FLAGS, ","),
       function(x) paste(gsub("(\\n)?20(0|1[0123]).*?(, |$)", "", trimws(x)), collapse=" "))

[1] "  2016CHAIRCOUNCIL" ""                   ""
```

Note that a "\n" is missing at the beginning and there is an additional (set of) space(s) at the beginning of the first element. The "\n" is removed be `trimws`. This makes the string a bit easier to work with. The additional spaces can be removed by wrapping the above expression in `trimws`, for example, `trimws(sapply(strsplit(...)))`.

**additional data**

```
FLAGS <- c("2011PRESIDENTS, \n2012CHAIRMANSCOUNCIL, \n2016CHAIRCOUNCIL", "", "2012COI")
```

Comment: Thanks lmo! Unfortunately, I'm getting some errors, no fault of your own. I should have elaborated more on my data frame. Flags is just one column of my data frame. When I run:

Comment: Thanks lmo! Unfortunately, I'm getting some errors, no fault of your own. I should have elaborated more on my data frame. Flags is just one column of my data frame. When I run: data2$FLAGS<-data2$FLAGS[-grep("20(0|1[0123])", data2$FLAGS)]' or the other grep, I receive the error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "FLAGS", value = c("2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO",  : 
 replacement has 1257 rows, data has 1504. So, some rows are deleted because they only have strings with years less than 2014? And, I'm left with a vector that can't fit into the data frame because it doesn't match df size?

Comment: Thanks. That definitely helps the length problem, but it turns an entire row of FLAGS into NA if there are any years within that row element that are in [2000-2013]. But I only want those specific year elements of the row deleted, not the entire turned to NA. For instance, a few rows of FLAGS may look something like: `data2$FLAGS<-c("2014a, 2015b", "2012a, 2017b", "2001a", "2002c, 2003a, 2014b, 2016b")` and I'd like data2$FLAGS to like `data2$FLAGS<-c("2014a, 2015b", "2017b", "NA", "2014b, 2016b")`

Comment: you are not adequately describing your actual problem. For example, it sounds like you are trying to manipulate a data.frame, but you only supplied a vector. I suggest that you post a new question that incorporates our solutions, but describes this latest issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution using `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
FLAGS[sapply(str_extract_all(FLAGS, '[0-9]{4}'),
             function(x) !any(as.integer(x) < 2014))]
```

This solution assumes you may have more than one year in each value. If that is not the case, you can do something more simple like:

```
FLAGS[as.integer(str_extract(FLAGS, '[0-9]{4}')) >= 2014]
```

Assuming `FLAGS` is as follows:

```
FLAGS
[1] "2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO" "2001ANNUALCONFERENCECOMM"       
[3] "\n2011GOVERNANCE"                "\n2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT"       
[5] "2013NEWMEMBERNOMINATOR"          "\n2014PUSPONSOR, \nPHOTO"
```

You get result as:

```
[1] "2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO" "\n2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT"       
[3] "\n2014PUSPONSOR, \nPHOTO"
```

**EDITING ANSWER BASED ON QUESTION EDIT ABOVE**

You can keep only values with 2014 or above and fill with NAs otherwise as follows:

```
data2$FLAGS <- ifelse(as.integer(str_extract(data2$FLAGS, '\\d+')) >= 2014,
                      data2$FLAGS, NA)
```

Result is as follows:

```
[1] "2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT, \nPHOTO" NA                               
[3] NA                                "\n2014PAGEJAMPARTICIPANT"       
[5] NA                                "\n2014PUSPONSOR, \nPHOTO"
```

Comment: Thanks Gopala! What if Flags is just one column in my data frame though? If you can see my comment to @Imo's answer I'm left with a vector that has less rows(elements) than the data frame and that leads to an error.  Furthermore, I believe your first method only gives a response True or False to the FLAGS vector if at least one string within a row of FLAGS satisfies the sapply. If some values within each element of FLAGS do satisfy the sapply method I'd still like to print/show the remaining parts of that row, not remove the entire element. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you do that assignment? You probably want to filter the rows and keep the ones that match condition? In that case, using `data2[as.integer(str_extract(data2$FLAGS, '[0-9]{4}')) >= 2014, ]` should do the trick. You can filter a column, and assign back to full data frame as there will be mismatch in length.

Comment: I'm not concerned with Flags before 2014, but some rows have Flags from years before and after 2014, so I don't want to delete an entire row just because one instance within that row element satisfies the condition. I just want to remove that particular instance from the row element. For instance, a few rows of FLAGS may look something like: `data2$FLAGS<-c("2014a, 2015b", "2012a, 2017b", "2001a", "2002c, 2003a, 2014b, 2016b")` and I'd like data2$FLAGS to like `data2$FLAGS<-c("2014a, 2015b", "2017b", "NA", "2014b, 2016b")`

Comment: So I'm thinking I can use a regex inside a gsub to remove specific row elements that have a year before 2014. I'm thinking the regex will be something like, `"20(0|1[0123])(anything in between),"` the comma is the delimiter between strings within a row, so if I use a syntactically correct regex inside a gsub I should replace any element in Flag with a year before 2014 with a blank (that is, just delete it, BUT not the entire row!)

Comment: Can you add all this detail to the question and I will modify my answer? This is different from the question you posted. :)

Comment: Take a look at my modified answer. That should work, I think.